# Use variable to call resource

Tags: java, android

Just try to create my code more compact.
I have a set of strings:

```
<string name = "A1">Some text</string>
<string name = "A2">More text</string>
...
<string name = "Z1">Different text</string>
```

All letter have a value from 1 to 4. I need to shot it in TextView according to condition. All conditions saved in array uan[]

```
if (uan[0] > 10 && uan[0] < 20) {
   textView.setText(getString(R.string.A1));
} else if (uan[0]>20 && uan[0]<40) {
   textView.setText(getString(R.string.A1));
} else if ...
```

I don't want to create a LONG-LONG set of conditions and try to create cycle. All type of conditions stored in other array conditionsType[]

```
String varAppend;
for (int i=0; i>uan.lenght; i++) {
 if (uan[i] >10 && uan [i] <20 ) {
    varAppend = "R.string."+varAppend[i]+uan[i]; /*here logical error, but I think to solve it */
    textView.setText(getString(varAppend)); /*Code doesn't work*/
 }
}
```

But I dont' know how to get string from resources through variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using string array as a resource instead:

```
<array name="sample">
    <item>A1</item>
    <item>A2</item>
    <item>A3</item>
    <item>A4</item>
    ...
    <item>Z4</item>
</array>
```

Afterwards just use the following code to access the array

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (although it is discouraged as not effective) :)

http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/

Just get the ID by name and then fetch by it.

Answer (score 0):

varAppend must be an int in

```
textView.setText(getString(varAppend))
```

> **String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int id) throws NotFoundException**
>
> **public String getString (int id)**
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the string value associated with a
>   particular resource ID. It will be stripped of any styled text
>   information.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **id**  The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt tool. This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry. The
>   value 0 is an invalid identifier

Try Using

> **getResources().getIdentifier()**

but the documentation says:  **use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.**